# Does Chrome's built-in "side-by-side" windows feature work on any platform except Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, fullscreen

I've recently been making use of the full-screen mode in various applications to help keep my focus centered on whatever I happen to be doing at the time.  To this end I'm using Chrome in full-screen mode as well.

This works great, but I find a lot of screen estate is wasted on my 30inch monitor.  I easily have enough room to run two tabs side-by-side.

I did some googling and whilst I found that there are several extension which basically insert HTML frames into a single tab to allow you to browse two sites (not very elegant from what I can see) there is apparantly a built-in feature from Google that lets you do this quite neatly.

See the [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn97WbalJwM).  The trouble is that this doesn't seem to work for me on OS X.  I'm using a recent Chromium build so I should have pretty cutting edge code.  Does anyone know if there is something I'm missing?  Is there a modifier key that needs to be pressed to make this feature work os is it just Windows only for now?

Comment: As mentioned, it's a feature of Windows 7. If you really want it on OS X, look into [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That side-by-side feature (Aero Snap) is actually part of the [Windows Aero GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) and available to all programs in Windows 7.  It's not part of Google Chrome.

I wish Aero also included something exactly like Exposé.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer to paradroid and Jamie Schembri but they are both wrong, it is not a part of windows 7 because it works on XP. And the Chrome UI give more side by side option than Win 7.

It doesn't work on other platform, but I don't know why.

Comment: No, we are not wrong.  Did you look at the linked video?  You cannot do that in XP.  You can tile side by side in XP, but that is not that same thing.

Comment: I can do that on XP, the proof : http://i.imgur.com/jKelA.png

Comment: That's only part of what this conversation is about.